# Retrieving email address from a log file

Tags: email, regex, extract

I have a log file which contains a lot of text as shown below. Would like to extract the email address which falls between *emailAddress* and *status* strings. I am open to any option which runs on Ubuntu, but would like to automate it.

> bouncedRecipients\":[{\"emailAddress\":\"**praveen@gmail.com**\",\"status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
perl -ne 'if(/emailAddress..:..(.+?)\\\"/){print "$1\n"}' logfile.txt
```

This Perl snippet will go through the file line by line and look for the string "emailAddress" followed by:

- any two characters (`..`), this will match `\"`,
- `:`,
- any two characters (`..`), this will match `\"`.

It then saves the following characters (until the next `"`) into `$1`. Finally, it prints `$1`.

NOTE: This assumes that **every** email address in your logfile has the same format as what you have given in your question.